# Trying to use HashMap to associate letters to numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to use Hashmap to make a dictionary of 26 key-value pairs. I'm trying to link each letter of the alphabet to a number, and then iterate through a string and letter by letter print the letter values from the HashMap.

This is what I tried:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put("a", 2);
    hm.put("b", 3);
    hm.put("c", 5);
    hm.put("d", 7);
    hm.put("e", 11);

    String word = new String("bed");
    char arr[] = word.toCharArray();
    for(char c: word) {
        System.out.println(hm.get(c));
    }
  }
}
```

My Output when compiled was:

```
Note: HashMapDemo.java uses unchecked or unsafe op  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.  
1 error
```

My Output when run anyway was:

```
 Null
```

I don't get why it can't find the letter in the hashmap. Is it because the hashmap keys are strings not chars? If it is i'm not sure what to do still.

Answer (score 3):

you should get value by String not from char .since map contain Strings.c is a char .by concatenate with a String `c+""` you can change it to String.and also `char c: word` is not correct it should be `char c: arr` because word isn't a array it's just a String.and you can use `String.valueOf(c);` also for turn char  to String

change

```
hm.get(c)
```

to

```
String.valueOf(c)
```

or

```
hm.get(Character.toString(c))
```

or

```
hm.get(c+"")
```

```
   HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put("a", 2);
    hm.put("b", 3);
    hm.put("c", 5);
    hm.put("d", 7);
    hm.put("e", 11);

    String word = new String("bed");
    char arr[] = word.toCharArray();
    for(char c: arr) {
        System.out.println(hm.get(String.valueOf(c)));
    }
```

Comment: This will fix it. But no +1 because a) missing generic type on HashMap, b) use of String constructor, c) `c+""` instead of `String.valueOf()`  ;-)

Comment: @Thilo but i have declare lot of methods to convert char to String .and yes i change main one to Character.toString(c);

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your `HashMap` contains `String` keys, but you try to get a `Character` from it.

You can fix it by making the keys Character as well:

```
Map<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
hm.put('a', 2);
hm.put('b', 3);   // Note the single quotes !
hm.put('c', 5);
hm.put('d', 7);
hm.put('e', 11);

String word = "bed";
for(char c: word.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(hm.get(c));
}
```

Also note that I typed the `HashMap`. That is highly recommended, the compiler will even warn if you don't. However, in this case, the improved type checking will not have caught your error, unfortunately (you can still call `get` with anything, not just the key type).

Comment: +1 for your common sense answer. and sorry to edit your post :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know How I could add up the letter values instead of printing them?

Comment: @user3591815: You can have an `int` variable, start it at `0` and then accumulate into it for each letter inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate arr i.o. word. And map's key is Java object.
try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        hm.put("a", 2);
        hm.put("b", 3);
        hm.put("c", 5);
        hm.put("d", 7);
        hm.put("e", 11);
        String word = new String("bed");
        char arr[] = word.toCharArray();
        for (char c : arr) {
            System.out.println(hm.get(String.valueOf(c)));
        }
    }
```